# Calculate the limit of the series (measure theory)

Tags: limits

Is this solution correct?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} { \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} { {1}\over{k^2}} \left(1- {{\min(k,n)}\over{n} }\right)}$$ We consider two cases:
$$\min(k,n)=n$$ we have: $${{1}\over{k^2}} {(1 - 1)} = 0 \to \lim_{n\to \infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}0}= 0 $$ and for $$\min(k,n)=k $$ we have: $$ 0 \le  { {1}\over{k^2}} \left(1- {{k}\over{n} }\right) \le {{1}\over{k^2}} $$ so $$\lim_{n\to\infty} {\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {{1}\over{k^2}}} = {{\pi^{2}}\over{6}} $$ The command says to apply the bounded convergence theorem, but this statement applies to the integral and I don't know if my solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

From your observation that for $k\geq n$, the terms are $0$, we get :
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} { {1}\over{k^2}} \left(1- {{\min(k,n)}\over{n} }\right) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}  \sum_{k=1}^{n} { {1}\over{k^2}} \left(1- {{k}\over{n} }\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}  \sum_{k=1}^{n}  {{1}\over{k^2}} - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{{1}\over{k}}\\
\end{align*}
One can argue that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ is of order $\ln(n)$ and so the RHS of the limit goes to $0$. And so the whole limit is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: your solution is for $$n\geq k  $$so we have $$ \min(k,n) = k $$?

Comment: Well, my solution is not for any $n$ or $k$, those are variable introduced in the limit and the sum. my solution is merely a solution not using the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

No. We can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem to solve this. We work in the space of sequences with the counting measure. Notice that $0\leq \frac{\min(k,n)}{n}\leq 1$ so $0\leq 1 - \frac{\min(k,n)}{n}\leq 1$. This is enough to show that the sequence of functions $f_n(k) = \frac{1}{k^2}\Big(1 - \frac{\min(k,n)}{n}\Big)$ are dominated by the integrable function $g(k)=\frac{1}{k^2}$ in the counting measure. Now for a fixed $k$ we have that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(k) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{\min(n,k)}{n}}{k^2}=\frac{1}{k^2}$$
Hence by the dominated convergence theorem we have that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}\Big(1 - \frac{\min(k,n)}{n}\Big)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\Big(1 - \frac{\min(k,n)}{n}\Big) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$